# How to run different role for different hosts in single ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible, automation, dependencies, ansible-playbook

I have 3 ansible playbook.

```
my_ansible
├── hosts
├── play1.yaml
├── play2.yaml
├── play3.yaml
└── roles
    ├── role1
    ├── role2
    └── role3
```

**hosts**

```
[play1]
host1

[play2]
host2

[play3]
host3
```

Now, when I run `play3`, I want to run `play2(role2)` on `host2` and `play1(role1)` on `host1`.

I check, [role-dependency](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies), but that apply on same host, means, if I add `role-dependency` in `role3` for `role1` and `role2`, then these 2 roles will run against `host3`.

I want to make sure, `play1` runs on `host1` only, `play2` runs on `host2` only and `play3` runs on `host3` only.

I try to find the `playbook` dependency, but no luck yet.

If is there any better way to solve this, then I am ready to head into that way too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way to achieve this is to create a master playbook and define the order of playbooks there.

> It is possible to include playbooks inside a master playbook. [...] The plays and tasks in each playbook listed will be run in the order they are listed, just as if they had been defined here directly.

See [Ansible documentation on playbooks reuse includes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_reuse_includes.html#importing-playbooks)

In order to achieve that `play3` runs `play2` and `play1` as well one would just need to define a master playbook like this:

```
---
- import_playbook: play3.yml
- import_playbook: play2.yml
- import_playbook: play1.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand, but I think you're saying your problem is you don't want to run play3 without first running play2 and play1?

I don't know a way to enforce this, but I can think of a few ways to make it more convenient.

First, just put all three plays into one file, then when you run one, you run them all.  If you want to occasionally run play1 without play2 and play3, use tags.  With tags, you could make play1 and play2 have the play3 tag, so you'd never run play3 without play1 and play2 by accident.

I usually put my ansible-playbook command into a script file so I don't have to remember it.  If you like doing that, you can make the script launch the three plays.  It's especially nice when you have co-workers who don't know ansible so well.  EG I make a file called `run.sh` that contains:

`ansible-playbook -i hosts myplay.yaml $@`

The `$@` is bash for add any args, so I can then do `./run.sh -t play1` and stuff like that.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I updated my question, sorry for the confusion, but I want to make sure, each play run on different hosts.

Comment: Oh, well if you've got separate plays, each play can have a different hosts entry.

Comment: yes, but how to give dependency for play? like when I run `play3` it should run `play2` and `play1`